# CSS3 fading out text

Tags: css, gradient, blur

I've been trying to get my text to fade out. I've tried some codes I've found on the internet, but they seem to be only for block elements.

Comment: you have try your code in JSFIDDLE?

Comment: what is he "code" you are talking about. paste some sample or jsfiddle link

Comment: They only work on block elements, while text is a inline element.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Never mind, I've found my own solution.

```
blablablabla<span class="readmore">blablablabla</span>

.readmore {
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 40%);
}
```

Unfortunately, only works on webkit.

Comment: I used it as below: -webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 80%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%); Because i thought that is most usual at looking. Thanks again.

Comment: That solution seems to always fade, not just fade on overflow.

Answer (score 8):

Here is [Fiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/Ff9JL/) , you can try likes this .

### html

```
<ul>
<li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean vestibulum massa     nec mi porta ut dictum dolor consectetur. Nunc imperdiet fermentum mauris, aliquam rhoncus magna suscipit eget. Cras neque velit, posuere ut pulvinar eu, faucibus sit amet tellus. Nullam sed orci tempus risus commodo commodo.</li>
</ul>
```

### css

```
body {
font-family: 'Lucida Grande', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
font-size: 13px;
 }

 ul { margin: 20px; padding: 0; }

 li {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
background-color: #fff;
 }
 li:after {
content: "";
pointer-events: none;
position: absolute;
width: 100px;
height: 100%;
top: 0; right: 0;

background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
 }

 /*
 This piece of code works great too, but only on Webkit Browsers!
 li {
color: white;
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
white-space: nowrap;
-webkit-mask-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 85%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 100%);
 }
 */
```

Comment: Is there's a way without `white-space: nowrap;`?

Comment: What if I need two gradients at right and bottom sides of text block?

Answer (score 3):

For **Googlers**, here is a simple generic solution I figured out after scouring the internet.

```
.excerpt {
  position: relative;
}

.excerpt::before {
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, transparent, white);
}
```

You can play with the parameters of `linear-gradient` to get different results, such as `to right`, or `transparent 25%`.

[Try the Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/KampsDuac/quf2uqo3/)

Comment: Good if the background is a solid color. Otherwise it will be a mess.

Answer (score 1):

For the folks coming here from the future, **CSS4** probably already includes:

```
text-overflow: fade;
```

https://drafts.csswg.org/css-ui-4/#text-overflow

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow

Greetings from 2017.

Comment: Unfortunately I think your clairvoyance was [faulty](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-overflow#Browser_compatibility).  (However, as I write this, your rep is the same as the current year. *creepy...*)