# How to make text on the end fade out with gradient background?

Tags: css, text, gradient, opacity, fadeout

I already have an element with an image as a background. Is it possible make a text on the end fade out just like in [this question 
[image]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17500407/css3-fading-out-text)

The problem is that the background image already have a gradient and I need the text on it just to become transparent without any modifications in the background.

Comment: I am not sure if I made it clear enough. Take the grey rectangle with a vertical gradient here above. How could I make the text: "CAREERS 2.0" fade out horizontally on the same background?

Comment: Yes. it's posible. Just use the code provided in the answer from MarioErmando (only supported in webkit)

Answer (score 4):

You say that you don't want to modify its `background-image` because it has another image already. But be aware that with CSS3 you can use [multiple backgrounds](http://www.css3.info/preview/multiple-backgrounds/).

But if you really don't want to modify its `background-image`, you could modify its `:after`'s `background-image`:

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/NbZbg/)

```
p {
  position: relative;
  line-height: 1.25em;
}

p:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient( to left, #fff, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 1.25em;
  content: '';
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the code on http://jsfiddle.net/Ff9JL/. This seems to be what you are looking for. Take a look at the li:after css code.

```
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(right, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
background-image: linear-gradient(to left, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1), rgba(255, 255, 255, 0));
```

Comment: This just puts the gradient on the background, but I need the text to fade out not the background